# Back button disappearing from screen

Tags: ios, swift

I've looked up answers online but it doesn't seem to have anything to do with Navigation Controller title.

Here is my View Controller visualisation:

[image]

When I touch a cell on the initial Table view ("Pick a Task") I am directed to the Navigation Controller through a modal segue.

The first View in this Navigation Controller is the "Room Controller".

Here I press another cell and am directed to the "Room Details" View through a modal segue.

After pressing 'back' here there is no longer a 'back' button in the "Room Controller". It just disappeared.

Why is this happening, does anyone know?

Comment: do the navigation bar and the title of the view controller remain the same, only the back button goes away?

Comment: From what we can see from the screenshot, you're probably instantiating a new RoomController (there is a segue pointing to it from the details) instead of dismissing the modal. This gets you a controller without a navigation controller as container and thus loosing the nav bar (and the button), but this is only speculation, if you could post some code it would be definitely helpful. And one more thing... why not using pushes instead to get all this for free?

Comment: It might be when you are dismissing the modal view controller the back button instance you are using it getting released. It would be better to use the push segue instead of modal. Modal are to be used when you are loading some view specifically from the storyboard which is apart from the flow or a standalone XIB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What is actually happening:**

There is no back button anymore because the segue which has the Room Details as the source and Room Controller as the destination causes another instance of the RoomController to be instantiated and presented on screen. Since the segue destination is the Room Controller and not it's navigation controller, there is no navigation bar present, hence no back button.

**Solution:**

I recommend you to use [unwind segues](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2298/_index.html) for going back and not regular segues since they create a new instance of the destination controller when performed.

Alternatively, you could programmatically dismiss the room details controller from the room controller (i.e. using delegation for more flexibility).

Comment: This is probably the correct answer. One minor note... no need to use delegation for dismissing, you just call dismiss on self and it forwards the message to its presenter automatically if needed

Comment: The presenting view controller is responsible for dismissing the view controller it presented. Since when you call `dismissViewController:animated:completion` within the Room Details Controller the message is forwarded downwards within the navigation stack, the message arrives at the presenting view controller and the result is the same. In addition, delegation may be helpful in the future if the user changes something in the Room Details Controller and these changes need to be reflected in the Room Controller.